# Running Windows Explorer from Windows 2000 under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, compatibility, windows-2000, windows-shell

I dislike the Windows Explorer built in to Windows 7. Is there a way to start the classic Windows Explorer that is present on Windows 2000 (both the panel and the file manager) under Windows 7?

I prefer Explorer from Windows 2000 over that from Win XP.

I have tried both the Explorer from Windows XP and 2000 but the XP Explorer calls some unimplemented function in ntdll on start (with an error). When run in compatibility mode the Explorer from Win 2000 at least does not report any errors but instead just silently exits.

Comment: Seems subjective to me. I think they're thinking "why are you doing this". (I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 4):

`Classicshell` does a good job of using a Windows 2000 style shell, and is completely configurable. It's also freeware.

The windows 7 shell has a number of `features` that some of us oldies who grew up with NT4/95/2000 take a good deal of getting used to, so i don't think that the 'subjective' comment is considered fair.

There was a project many years ago to run the NT4 shell on Windows 2000 (fred vorck), and the 95 shell on Windows 98 (98lite).  Both of these required severe file patching to get the things to work, and not all things worked that well.

On the other hand, there are shells that replace bits of explorer, in much the same way that Win31 shells work, that seem to do quite a good job of things.

Comment: Thanks, I know about Classic Shell, It does not make Explorer usable, I currently use 4 residfent programs (Shell Folder Fix, 7 Taskbar Tweaker, Classic Shell, Ruslat95) and 2 hack programs to make Explorer better, but it is not enough. Regarding 98Lite you possibly have wrong information, one could use the Explorer from Win95 under Win98 just by copying 3 files, which I did actually myself.

Comment: The way fred vorck patched nt4 explorer was to tell it to look for a different shell32.dll.  With 98lite, even though you provide the filrs, it still patches them.  You could compare the installed versions to the ones you feed 98lite.

Comment: I copied Shell32.dll from Win95 and it worked well.